# ImportError: No module named analysis.clustering.algorithms

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to understand python code on text summarization (https://github.com/giorgosera/pythia/blob/dev/analysis/summarization/summarization.py) but when I am running this code, it is showing error:

```
ImportError: No module named analysis.clustering.algorithms
```

How I can import this module?

Answer (score 0):

Its trying to import this module:

https://github.com/giorgosera/pythia/blob/dev/analysis/clustering/algorithms.py

Have you cloned the **pythia** repository?

**git clone https://github.com/giorgosera/pythia.git**

You may also need to run some setup scripts to build the cython extensions.